# Adding plots to GraphicsLayoutWidget using pyqt

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, pyqtgraph

I wanted to add plots to GraphicsLayoutWidget. However i tried with the code i have written which is below.

But now i wanted to changed i have two types of msgs one in live mode and in other recorded mode.
However i wanted to add one more plot item in live mode.

To be sure i also added some comments in the code to get some understanding for you.I only pasted some part of the code.

I searched already in stack but couldnt find answers which solves my thing.

```
from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtCore, QtGui
import threading
import pyqtgraph as pg
import socket
import psutil
import time
import struct
import sys
import collections
import os
import PySimpleGUI as sg

import easygui




visualize_recorded_msg = 1
driver_called_from_outside = 0

BufferLength = 500
marker_size = 14

if 0 == visualize_recorded_msg:
    if 0 == driver_called_from_outside:
        driver_name = 'sss'
else:
    name_of_the_recorded_file = 'sss.bin'



########################################################################################################################
def get_pid_and_kill(process_name):
    for proc in psutil.process_iter():
        if proc.name() == process_name:
            p = psutil.Process(proc.pid)
            p.terminate()
            print("Process " + process_name + " terminated")


if 0 == visualize_recorded_msg:
    if 0 == driver_called_from_outside:
        from subprocess import Popen

        get_pid_and_kill(driver_name.split(("/"))[-1])
        get_pid_and_kill(driver_name.split(("\\"))[-1])
        get_pid_and_kill("cmd.exe")
        Popen([driver_name])
        print("The driver started")
        time.sleep(1)

    # TCP/IP Socket creation
    HOST = '145.0.0.10'
    PORT = 8085

    try:
        socket_connection = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        socket_connection.settimeout(3)
        socket_connection.connect((HOST, PORT))
        socket_connection.settimeout(None)
        print("Socket successfully created")
    except socket.error as err:
        raise SystemExit("Socket creation failed with error %s" % err)
else:
    file_handle = open(name_of_the_recorded_file, 'rb')

    all_msgs = file_handle.read()
    file_handle.close()


def open_exit_button():
    even_name = 'kill the driver'
    layout = [[sg.Button(even_name, button_color=('white', 'springgreen4'))]]

    window = sg.Window('Configurations', layout)
    while True:  # Event Loop
        event, values = window.read(timeout=10)

        if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED or event == even_name:
            if 0 == visualize_recorded_msg:
                get_pid_and_kill(driver_name.split(("/"))[-1])
                get_pid_and_kill(driver_name.split(("\\"))[-1])
            os._exit(1)
            break

    window.close()


class Visualizer(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

        self.view = pg.GraphicsLayoutWidget()
        self.view.setWindowTitle('')

        self.w1 = self.view.addPlot(row=0, col=0, title='Accelerometer 1')
        self.w1.showGrid(x=True, y=True)
        self.w1.addLegend()
        self.w1.setLabel(axis='bottom', text='Time [s]')
        self.w1.setLabel(axis='left', text='')
        self.w1.curve2 = self.w1.plot(name='')
        self.w1.curve3 = self.w1.plot(name='')

        self.w2 = self.view.addPlot(row=1, col=0, title='')
        self.w2.showGrid(x=True, y=True)
        self.w2.addLegend()
        self.w2.setLabel(axis='bottom', text='Time [s]')
        self.w2.setLabel(axis='left', text='')
        self.w2.curve2 = self.w2.plot(name='')
        self.w2.curve3 = self.w2.plot(name='')

        self.w3 = self.view.addPlot(row=2, col=0, title='Average')
        self.w3.showGrid(x=True, y=True)
        self.w3.setLabel(axis='bottom', text='Time [s]')
        self.w3.setLabel(axis='left', text='')
        self.w3.curve1 = self.w3.plot()

        self.w4 = self.view.addPlot(row=3, col=0, title='result ')
        self.w4.showGrid(x=True, y=True)
        self.w4.setLabel(axis='bottom', text='Time [s]')
        self.w4.setLabel(axis='left', text='')
        self.w4.curve1 = self.w4.plot()

        self.a = collections.deque(maxlen=BufferLength)
        self.b = collections.deque(maxlen=BufferLength)
        self.c = collections.deque(maxlen=BufferLength)
        self.d = collections.deque(maxlen=BufferLength)
        self.e = collections.deque(maxlen=BufferLength)
        self.f = collections.deque(maxlen=BufferLength)

        self.view.show()

        self.prevFrameCnt = 0
        self.iteration_index = 0
        self.li_det = 0
        self.str_mot = 1

    @staticmethod
    def start():
        if (sys.flags.interactive != 1) or not hasattr(QtCore, 'PYQT_VERSION'):
            QtGui.QApplication.instance().exec_()

    def message_parser(self, data):
        out1 = struct.unpack("<L", data[0:4])[0]
        out2 = data[4]
        out3 = data[5]
        out4 = data[6]
        out5 = struct.unpack("<h", data[7:9])[0]
        out6 = struct.unpack("<H", data[9:11])[0]
        out7 = struct.unpack("<H", data[11:13])[0] 
        out8 = struct.unpack("<H", data[17:19])[0] 
        out9 = struct.unpack("<H", data[19:21])[0] 

        return [out1, out2, out3, out4, out5, out6, out7, out8, out9]

    def update(self):

        if 0 == visualize_recorded_msg:
            # Receive TCP/IP packet
            try:
                data = socket_connection.recv(64)
            except socket.timeout as e:
                print(e)
                return
            except (ConnectionResetError, OSError):
                raise SystemExit("Remote server closed")

            # Decode TCP/IP packet
            output = self.message_parser(data)
        else:
            msg_length = 21 
            try:
                data = all_msgs[self.iteration_index: self.iteration_index + msg_length]
                decode_output = self.message_parser(data)
                self.iteration_index += msg_length
            except:
                print('End of file')
                

        x = decode_output[0]
        y = decode_output[4]
        z = decode_output[5]
        x1 = decode_output[6]
        y1 = decode_output[7]
        z1 = decode_output[8]


        if self.prevFrameCnt == x:
            MovDet = decode_output[1]
            LiDet = decode_output[2]
            MotDet = decode_output[3]

            self.a.append(y)
            self.c.append(z1)
            self.d.append(y1)

            self.w2.curve2.setData(self.c, pen=None, symbol='t', symbolPen=None, symbolSize=marker_size,
                                   symbolBrush=(0, 114, 189))
            self.w2.curve3.setData(self.d, pen=None, symbol='t1', symbolPen=None, symbolSize=marker_size,
                                   symbolBrush=(217, 83, 25))
            self.w3.curve1.setData(self.a, pen=None, symbol='d', symbolPen=None, symbolSize=marker_size,
                                   symbolBrush=('g'))
            self.w4.curve1.setData(self.f, pen=None, symbol='o', symbolPen=None,
                                   symbolSize=marker_size,
                                   symbolBrush=(217, 83, 25))

            if (1 == self.li_det) or (105 == LiDet):
                self.li_det = 1

        else:
            MovDet = decode_output[1]
            LiDet = decode_output[2]
            MotDet = decode_output[3]

            self.b.append(z1)
            self.d.append(y1)
            
            self.w1.curve2.setData(self.b, pen=None, symbol='t', symbolPen=None, symbolSize=marker_size,
                                   symbolBrush=(0, 114, 189))
            self.w1.curve3.setData(self.d, pen=None, symbol='t1', symbolPen=None, symbolSize=marker_size,
                                   symbolBrush=(217, 83, 25))
            self.prevFrameCnt = x



        self.view.show()

    def animation(self):
        timer = QtCore.QTimer()
        timer.timeout.connect(self.update)
        timer.start(1)
        self.start()


def visualization():
    v = Visualizer()
    v.animation()


def main():
    if 0 == driver_called_from_outside:
        thread = threading.Thread(target=visualization)
        thread.start()
        open_exit_button()
    else:
        visualization()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: please provide a [mre], what is `gp`?

Comment: @eyllanesc params is some parameters file where i am keeping all my parameters in that file. In the above code that i posted you can ignore gp.all_msgs , instead you can take it as all_msgs which is list of bytes.

Comment: If you want help you must provide an MRE, the community should not clean up your code. The logic of the MRE is that any user can do a copy-paste and then execute the code having to obtain the same behavior that the OP describes. Please read [ask] and review the [tour]

Comment: @eyllanesc Thanks for your insights. I will post the updated code